# Scraping an xls file from javascript (web page) in R

Tags: javascript, r

I am attempting to create an R script that specifically details how to acquire the data I am using for analysis in R for reproducability reasons. Usually the first step is as simple as assigning a url for the xls file to a variable in R and proceeding from there, but the website I am scraping from seems to produce its xls files via javascript (A language I have no knowledge of).

Follow these steps to get to an example XLS:

1. Go to http://hcupnet.ahrq.gov/HCUPnet.jsp?Id=B08F84A071883804&Form=SelDXPR&JS=Y&Action=%3E%3ENext%3E%3E&_DXPR=DX1
2. Click "Principal Diagnosis"
3. Type "599.0" in the text box (without the quotation marks) and leave the radio button for "Each code separately" checked
4. Click "Next"
5. On this page check all of the radio buttons
6. Click "Next"
7. On this page check all of the radio buttons
8. Click "Next"

On this page you should see all of the data, as well as some links. One of these links is titled "Save results as an Excel spreadsheet". Clicking on this link will download an XLS file with the data to your computer.

I've inspected the element and can clearly see that it is querying a database, I'm just not entirely sure how to get that query into my R script to pull the xls file down.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I wasn't the down-voter, but you really didn't show any sign of "attempting" to create an R script (which is no doubt the reason for the down-vote).

Comment: The very first step of the script, importing the data, is my issue. I described assigning the url to a variable, and mentioned that it doesn't work in this case because of the use of javascript, a language I don't know. I don't think submitting a blank script would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

(not technically a full-on answer, perhaps, but the comment box doesn't allow real formatting)

[RSelenium](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/index.html) can perform all those actions. However, will there be many different selections/combinations of options? If not, you could just build a list of URLs like this one:

```
http://hcupnet.ahrq.gov/HCUPnet.jsp?Parms=H4sIAAAAAAAAACWJPQ.CMBgG_5KYMDACHSTGBgUT16fvtcrXoos_nybc5ab766evfDcU52vnonsVmlVWVfCnFIcQw9rXo0wEDIgsrGwk3ppkNQ0tTnb72BNPP7YX7jzyy6YDzbkdSuxNr2gAAAA6D4E19A7096C3AE9FD48005A5B0802A684BBBEB8
```

which goes right to that page for each download. You can capture that url by hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd> instead of actually downloading the XLS file and then copying the URL from the location bar.

On that page you can use the `XML` library or `rvest` to ingest and extract the `onclick` attribute following tag:

```
<a href="Javascript:void(0)" 
   onclick="window.open('HCUPnet.xls?Id=0A8C3E07CD01B562&amp;Form=DispTab&amp;JS=&amp;Action=%3E%3ENext%3E%3E&amp;__InDispTab=Yes&amp;_Results=Save&amp;_Results3=&amp;SortOpt=');">
<img height="19" src="arrow_off3.gif" alt="" align="absMiddle" width="15" border="0">
 Email a link to this page</a>
```

(I included the full anchor reference as you'll need to use that in the XPath or CSS selector to find that tag, but you might be able to get away with just doing an XPath or CSS "contains" for `HCUPnet.xls` in the `onclick` attribute, too).

Then, just extract the `HCUP…` string from there and prepend `http://hcupnet.ahrq.gov/` to it in a `download.file` call.